# multiline pattern for nested xml files in filebeat - logstash 7.0.1

Tags: xml, logstash, filebeat

I was trying to parse a typical xml log file from my windows machine using filebeat to logstash.

below is my xml example.

```
<?xml-stylesheet alternate="yes" href="file://c:/drive/bin/event_log.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<EventLog SetMinutes="800" Id="8000" Process="Player.exe">
<Clock ClockId="CLk-21e21412414=4-1341341414141"/>
<Entry serial_no="0" mcycle="2132424124-4141" Thread="player" ThreadId="tester" Seconds="11231243241.354123" Severity="info" >Local player details  - Receievd metrics
player has reached 1000 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 100 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 70 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 1000 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 100 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 70 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 400 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 100 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 30 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 103 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 130 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 70 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 1000 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 100 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 70 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 3300 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 100 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 70 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 1300 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 103 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 1000 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 100 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 70 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 1000 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 100 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 70 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 400 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 100 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 30 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 103 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 130 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 70 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 1000 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 100 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 70 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 3300 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 100 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 70 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 1300 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 103 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 733 level and need to get an xp
</Entry> 
</Eventlog>
```

Below is my filebeat multiline config.

```
multiline.pattern: '^<Entry|^=[a-z]'
    multiline.negate : false
    multiline.match: after
```

Below is my losgtash.conf xml filter

```
input{
 beats {
     port => 5044
}

}
filter{
  xml{
      source => "message"
      store_xml => true
      target => "doc"
      xpath => ["/Eventlog[@name='ThreadId']@value",  "ThreadId",
                        "/Eventlog[@name='Thread']@value",  "Thread",
                        "/Eventlog/Entry[@name='Secs']@value",  "Seconds",
                         "/Eventlog/Entry[@name='ThreadId']@value",  "ThreadID",
                        "/Eventlog/Entry/text()", "details"
                        ]
}
```

Can anyone help with this? Am i missing anything in the config of filebeat or logstash ?

Comment: What is your question? This configuration doesn't work for you? Are you getting any errors? What is the expected and actual result? Consider editing and clarifying the question.

Comment: Configuration doesn't work

Comment: Configuration doesnt work. Expected to see all the lines under 
```
<Entry 
wewqfqwfqwfqwef
asfasfasfasgasgasg
ASgfasgasgsagasgasg
ASgasgasgasgasggrwg
</Entry> 
```
in a single message